# Parsing JSON with JavaScript to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table:

```
<table class='headers'>
  <tr>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Height</th> 
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Occupation</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Male</td>
     <td>5'11</td> 
     <td>160</td>
     <td>35</td>
     <td>Doctor</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

If I had a JSON file with two more data sets, how can I parse them in Javascript so each new object creates a new tr?

```
jsonData = [
  {
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Height": 5'2,
    "Weight": 100,
    "Age": 25,
    "Occupation": "Lawyer"
  },
  {
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Height": 5'9,
    "Weight": 150,
    "Age": 23,
    "Occupation": "Student"
  }
 ]
```

I would need my new HTML to look like this:

```
 <table class='headers'>
  <tr>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Height</th> 
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Occupation</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Male</td>
     <td>5'11</td> 
     <td>160</td>
     <td>35</td>
     <td>Doctor</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
   <tr>
     <td>Female</td>
     <td>5'2</td> 
     <td>100</td>
     <td>25</td>
     <td>Lawyer</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

etc.

I've only parsed in Ruby before, and I had to 'require = json'' on the top of the file. Do I still have to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have JSON, you have an array *literal*. You don't want to parse it, you want to *traverse* (iterate) it.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you expect as answer, but if you wonder how to process arrays/objects, see [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196). If you don't know how to create DOM elements, start with http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to read the JSON file and parse the results

```
$.getJSON('file.json', function (response) {
    // this is where you would iterate over the json and create the element
});
```

Let me know if you need help iterating over the data and I will edit to provide more.

Comment: Thanks Carl. I just tried this and I had an error pop up in the console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load - Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

All my files are in the same folder, so I shouldn't have to require anything, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late but this javascript will do what you ask. One important note is that it collects the columns from the first object in the array. Therefor if other objects follow later on that have more columns, they will not be included in your list.

```js
//build table from ARRAY of jsonObjects
function dataToTable(gotData){
 var tableDiv = document.createElement('div');
 tableDiv.id = 'TABLE';
 var table = document.createElement('table')
    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    //build columHeaders
    var hrow = document.createElement('tr');
 for(col in gotData[0]){
  console.log(col, gotData[0][col]);
  var hcell = document.createElement('td');
  hcell.innerHTML = '<b>' + col + '</b>';
  hrow.appendChild(hcell);
 }
 tableBody.appendChild(hrow);
 //build dataRows
 for(row in gotData){
  var drow = document.createElement('tr');
  for(col in gotData[row]){
   var dcell = document.createElement('td');
   dcell.innerHTML = gotData[row][col];
   drow.appendChild(dcell);
  }
  tableBody.appendChild(drow);
 }
 table.appendChild(tableBody);
 tableDiv.appendChild(table);
 document.body.appendChild(tableDiv);
};
```

Comment: sorry the code indentations went all funky for some reason :/